# For loop over list while filtering

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-loop

I have 2 DataFrames called `df1` and `df2`, where they both have the same column names. I wish to run a for loop over unique dates, from `df1` and apply the same date filter to `df2`. I created a list of unique dates and then tried to iterate through that. However what I have is throwing errors.

Here is what I have:

```
val unique_weeks = df1.select(df1("date")).distinct

for( week <- unique_weeks) {
  val df1_filtered = df1.filter($"date" === week)
  val df2_filtered = df2.filter($"date" === week)
  /// will run a join here and more code 

}
```

I think `<-` this part may be incorrect - but not sure how I can filter the DataFrames using another method.

Here is the error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 35 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 35.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 399, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema [1591772400000]
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.$eq$eq$eq(Column.scala:267)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkMain.scala:880)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkMain.scala:878)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] 
[error] Driver stacktrace:
[error] org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 35 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 35.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 399, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema [1591772400000]
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.$eq$eq$eq(Column.scala:267)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkMain.scala:880)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkMain.scala:878)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] 
[error] Driver stacktrace:
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
[error]     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:917)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:915)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:915)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2286)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2286)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2286)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreach(Dataset.scala:2285)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain$.main(SparkMain.scala:878)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.scala)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema [1591772400000]
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.$eq$eq$eq(Column.scala:267)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkMain.scala:880)
[error]     at spark_pkg.SparkMain$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkMain.scala:878)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last Compile / bgRun' for the full output
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 137 s (02:17), completed Aug 20, 2020 1:16:02 PM
```

Comment: What exceptions are getting thrown?

Comment: i haven't run the full program since its long but my IDE is giving me a red line under `<-`

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say it's throwing errors, which could reasonably interpreted as being at runtime.

Comment: In any event, what does the IDE say the error under the red line is?

Comment: @LeviRamsey i updated the question to include the error on run time

Comment: In this case it looks like it's the query `=== week` that's blowing up.  `week` has the type `Row`, so I'd suggest asking how to extract the date from a `Row` to a type that you can compare in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dataframe is not an iterator, and therefore, you cannot run a for loop over it. You can run something like this - but I don't think it will do what you're hoping to achieve based on your other code.

```
unique_weeks.foreachPartition{ weeks : Iterator[YourData] => 

  for( week <- weeks) {
  
  }    
}
```

Your question suggests your mental model of what a dataframe is and how Spark works is not quite complete. Think of a Dataframe more as a `List[List[YourData]]`, except each inner `List[YourData]` is located on an independent piece of a machine, and may not necessarily know or interact with *any* of the other `List`s until you collect them back to the driver.

Comment: Spark 3.0's scaladoc indicates that dataframes have a `foreach` method.